# PDCurses KEY_ENTER does not work

Tags: c++, curses, pdcurses

Lets start with what my code looks like then I will explain my problem:

```
int main {

char ch;  //Stores key presses

initscr();
raw();  
nonl();  
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);  
noecho();  

//Some code  

ch = getch();  
switch (ch) {
    case KEY_UP:{
        //Code that works
        break;
    }
    case KEY_ENTER:{
        //Some code- that doesn't work problem being the above
        break;
    }
    //Other case statements
}
```

Now the problem:
The problem I run into if you haven't already worked it out is that when ever I press the enter/return key on my keyboard absolutely nothing happens.
I have tried changing the `KEY_ENTER` to `'\n'` - didn't work - even changed  the `char ch` which when through multiple iterations including `int` and `wchar_t`.
All to no avail, and before you say search for answers and send me packing my bags to go onto a perilous adventure through every corner of the interwebs, I have already tried that, if I hadn't I wouldn't have ventured here, in search of aid.
So now my search has brought me here and I ask of you - the lovely people of the interwebs - to help me in my search of the answer I have been looking for
And to who ever may be valiant enough to answer it I give you my up most gratitude and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `case '\r':`. (For good measure, you could do `case '\r': case '\n': case KEY_ENTER:`, as is basically done in testcurs.c, to capture all possibilities.) The call to `nonl()` is why you're getting '\r' instead of '\n'.

As for `KEY_ENTER`, my only excuse is that it's marked "not reliable" in the PDCurses comments. I could pretend that it's meant to represent the keypad's "Enter" key, rather than the key usually marked "Return" in the main part of the keyboard... except that PDCurses also has `PADENTER`, specifically for that purpose. In truth, like a lot of things in PDCurses, the reason `KEY_ENTER` is there, and defined the way it is, is a bit of a historical mess.